# Error when counting query array in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What I'm trying to do is emulate a random token that is going to be sent from another system through the url. This other system will also insert 3 values in the database:

- ID
- IP
- Current time

Now when, at another time, a client accesses the application, it must have an identical IP and ID as the system that first accessed it, and the time difference must be under 30 minutes, otherwise the session is not authenticated and the machine will be restricted and sent to an error page.

I'm having a problem:

- when I perform `session[] sessionArray = a.ToArray();` the following error appears:

> {"FUNCTION cgdimport.DiffMinutes does not exist"}

As explained by WiiMaxx:

> no your ERROR isn't there your error is
>   EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(b.start, DateTime.Now). because your b
>   doesnt contains a function called DiffMinutes()

So I tried an alternative:

```
ar a = (from b in data.session 
where b.idsession == sessionid 
&& b.ip == clientip 
&& DateTime.Now <= b.start + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0) 
select b);
```

But it gives me the following error:

> DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.

And another:

```
var a = (from b in data.session
                            where b.idsession == sessionid
                            && b.ip == clientip
                            && DateTime.Now <= b.start.AddMinutes(30)
                            select b);
```

But this error appears:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   AddMinutes(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into
>   a store expression.

```
public ActionResult SessionController()
    {
        var data = new cgdimportEntities();



        //Request sessionnid from the URL
        if (!Request.QueryString["token"].IsEmpty() && Request.QueryString["token"] != null)
        {
            //Obtain client IP 
            string clientip = HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;


            //Request sessionid from url
            string sessionid = Request.QueryString["token"];
            //string sessionid = token;

            //Dummy Test Insert

            var sessionvar = new session {idsession = sessionid, ip = clientip, start = DateTime.Now};

            data.session.Add(sessionvar);


            try { data.SaveChanges(); }

            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}", validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                                    validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                }

            //old code
            //var a = (from b in data.session
                        //where b.idsession == sessionid
                        //&& b.ip == clientip
                        //&& EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(b.start, DateTime.Now) < 30
                        //select b);
            //old code
            //var a = (from b in data.session 
                       //where b.idsession == sessionid 
                       //&& b.ip == clientip 
                       //&& DateTime.Now <= b.start + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0) 
                       //select b);

            //new code
              var a = (from b in data.session
                         where b.idsession == sessionid
                         && b.ip == clientip
                         && DateTime.Now <= b.start.AddMinutes(30)
                         select b);


            int count = 0;


            //ERROR HERE! ERROR HERE!
            session[] sessionArray = a.ToArray();


            foreach (var i in sessionArray)
            {
                count++;
            }

            //if 0 rows are counted
            if (count == 0)
            {
                Session["authenticated"] = "false";
                return RedirectToAction("Erro", "Login", new { erro = "No rows counted" });
            }
            //Once all queries are verified, the user is authenticated
            Session["authenticated"] = "true";
            return RedirectToAction("Painel", "Data");
        }
            Session["authenticated"] = "false";
            return RedirectToAction("Erro", "Login", new { erro = "Query is null" });
   }
```

Comment: no your ERROR isn't there your error is `EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(b.start, DateTime.Now)`. because your **b** doesnt contains a function called `DiffMinutes()`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

I tried an alternative:


`var a = (from b in data.session
                                where b.idsession == sessionid
                                && b.ip == clientip
                                && DateTime.Now <= b.start + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0)
                                select b);`


But it gives me the following error:

DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.

Comment: try `b.start.AddMinutes(30)` instead of `b.start + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0)`

Comment: Tried that, gives another error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddMinutes(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: ok i give up with this linq i'm not good with it sry, but let's try a last thing `DateTime.Now.Ticks <= b.start.Ticks`

Comment: Doesn't work, gives the following error:

"The specified type member 'Ticks' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because one argument of the `DateTime` comparison is a constant (with respect to the query) you could take `AddMinutes` off the query which should remove the exception:

```
DateTime nowMinus30Minutes = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30);

var a = (from b in data.session
         where b.idsession == sessionid
            && b.ip == clientip
            && nowMinus30Minutes <= b.start
         select b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) to add the minutes

```
ar a = (from b in data.session 
 where b.idsession == sessionid 
 && b.ip == clientip 
 && DateTime.Now <= System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(b.start, 30)
 select b);
```

Comment: I can't seem to use EntityFunctions, WiiMaxx said to try something silar.

Your code gives me the following error:

"{"FUNCTION cgdimport.AddMinutes does not exist"}"

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with that error, but looks like you are missing a reference or are referencing an old library which doesn't contain that function ... which version of EntityFramework are you using? Maybe add more details of the error.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Professional 2012, so I guess that would make EF v. 5.

Details here [http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mBryjr8y]